# how can I make an array with outgoing array in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What I'm trying to achieve is this picture (please excuse my awful painting skills):  [image]

This is what I know have:

[image]

it's basically an array made by the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,cryptocode}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{DS Assignment 2}
\author{that's me}
 \date{February 2018}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand\LinearGraph[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,draw=gray, thick, minimum width=5mm}]
 \foreach \num/\lab [count=\c] in {#1} {
   \node[box,label=below:\lab] at (\c/2,0){$\num$};
 }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textbf{Exercise 6)} \\some text

$ \phantom{x}\hspace{20ex} $ \LinearGraph{1/0, 2/1, 2/2, 3/3}

\end{document}
```

How can I get what I want from what I have? Or if new code is needed, I wouldn't mind adding it. Please note that it's not the case that the arrows are going out from each cell to the other. I would like to be able to choose that and preferably one-sided arrows and I don't care about the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how you want to handle this with the macro thing you have going. However, you can add arrows as you wish to the macro if you simply name the nodes. `arrows.meta` makes it easy to choose arrow styles, including half-headed ones. Here's an example with one arrow of each kind.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\newcommand\LinearGraph[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,draw=gray, thick, minimum width=5mm}]
    \foreach \numb/\lab [count=\c] in {#1} {
      \node (n\c) [box,label=below:\lab] at (\c/2,0){$\numb$};
    }
    \draw [-{Stealth[left,bend]}] ([yshift=1.5pt]n1.south) [bend right=50] to ([yshift=1.5pt]n2.south);
    \draw [-{Stealth[bend]}] ([yshift=1.5pt]n2.south) [bend right=50] to ([yshift=1.5pt]n3.south);
    \draw [-{Stealth[right,bend]}] ([yshift=1.5pt]n3.south) [bend right=50] to ([yshift=1.5pt]n4.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\LinearGraph{1/0, 2/1, 2/2, 3/3}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrow variations]

## EDIT

For something more flexible, I'd be inclined to use a `pic` for the most straightforward solution. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{%
  linear graph/.search also={/tika},
  linear graph/.pic={
    \tikzset{
      linear graph/.cd,
      #1,
      /tikz/.cd
    }
    \coordinate (bo) at (0,0);
    \foreach \numb/\lab [count=\c, remember=\c as \clast (initially o)] in \lineargraphboxes
    {
      \node (b\c) [box, label={[text height=1.25ex]below:\lab}, anchor=west] at (b\clast.east){$\numb$};
    }
    \foreach \i/\j in \lineargrapharrows \draw [-{Stealth[bend]}] ([yshift=1.5pt]b\i.south) [bend right=50] to ([yshift=1.5pt]b\j.south);
    \foreach \i/\j in \lineargraphleftarrows \draw [-{Stealth[bend,left]}] ([yshift=1.5pt]b\i.south) [bend right=50] to ([yshift=1.5pt]b\j.south);
    \foreach \i/\j in \lineargraphrightarrows \draw [-{Stealth[bend,right]}] ([yshift=1.5pt]b\i.south) [bend right=50] to ([yshift=1.5pt]b\j.south);
  },
  box/.style={
    draw=gray, thick, minimum width=5mm, text height=1.5ex,
  },
  linear graph/.cd,
  boxes/.estore in=\lineargraphboxes,
  boxes=,
  arrows/.estore in=\lineargrapharrows,
  arrows=,
  left arrows/.estore in=\lineargraphleftarrows,
  left arrows=,
  right arrows/.estore in=\lineargraphrightarrows,
  right arrows=,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {linear graph = {boxes={1/0, 2/1, 2/2, 3/3}}};
  \pic at (0,-1)  {linear graph = {boxes={1/a, B/b, 20/c, 76.54/d, Aardvarks/e}, arrows={1/2,3/4}, left arrows={2/3}, right arrows={1/5,4/5}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This means that the first case will be drawn without arrows, whereas the second will have full arrows between the first and second and third and fourth boxes, a left arrow between the second and third, and right arrows between the first and fifth and fourth and fifth.

[image: variations: with and without arrows]

## EDIT EDIT

Here's what I don't recommend, as it will make your code more obscure. However, if you really want a macro, you can add

```
\newcommand\LinearGraph[1]{% not recommended!
  \tikz{\pic {linear graph = {#1}};}%
}
```

and then produce the same ticker-tape-type diagrams with

```
% not recommended!
\LinearGraph{boxes={1/0, 2/1, 2/2, 3/3}}
\LinearGraph{boxes={1/a, B/b, 20/c, 76.54/d, Aardvarks/e}, arrows={1/2,3/4}, left arrows={2/3}, right arrows={1/5,4/5}}
```

in your document.

Comment: i feel like this code is for one-time use only, but what if i want to use it repeatedly throughout the document?

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji Well, simplest would be to take the `tikzpicture` environment out and then use the macro followed by the arrows as required. You could arrange to pass things as arguments. However, this is a very anti-Ti*k*Z approach and will be quite difficult in terms of use.

Comment: That's unfortunate :/ especially considering how much of a noob i'm when in comes to TikZ

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji I'd probably use a `pic`, actually. See edit above. This lets you specify things with a key-value syntax, which is generally much easier to use than remember which arguments are which. This also makes it easier to handle things in the `pic`'s definition, so it should be easier to modify to suit your needs.

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji You could then make `\LinearGraph` a macro which takes an argument and just define it to create a `tikzpicture` containing the `linear graph` `pic` with the argument passed through as options. I wouldn't encourage this as it makes it much less obvious what your code is doing: it isn't even obvious that the macro has anything to do with Ti*k*Z. And generally, greater transparency is preferable, even if your code is slightly more verbose. The time you would save on typing is easily eaten later by trying to figure out what your macro was meant to do.

Comment: your edit fixed everything and was everything i needed! Thanks!

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji I've also added a macro version, though I really don't recommend this. I know it seems like a time-saver now, but it is so easy to forget what your code does that anything which increases opacity is better avoided. In the end, it is more efficient to use the slightly more verbose, but more self-explanatory, code.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

for above solution i define two arguments for new command: `#1` contain number of cells and  `#2` contain contents of cells and their labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\LinearGraph[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={rectangle,draw=gray, thick, minimum width=5mm}]
 \foreach \num/\lab [count=\c] in {#2}%
{
   \node (n\c) [box,label=below:\lab] at (\c/2,0){$\num$};
   \ifnum\c<#1
   \draw[shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt, ->, thick, red]
        (n\c.base) to [out=270, in=270, looseness=2] ++ (0.4,0);
   \fi
 }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\begin{document}
\[
\LinearGraph{4}{1/0, 2/1, 2/2, 3/2}
\]

\[
\LinearGraph{5}{1/0, 2/1, 2/2, 3/2, 4/3}
\]
\end{document}
```